# Cors no-access-control-allow-origin when trying to call B2C login

Tags: azure, react-redux, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-ad-b2c

I cannot resolve this error, i have a .net core web api, with a react application inside of it ( net core react template )

[image]

I have also added cors:

```
      services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("AllowMyOrigin",
            builder => builder.WithOrigins("https://localhost:44300")
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowCredentials()
            );
        });
```

I have tried multiple things but i cant get past this error.

I have found loads of material online to try and nothing seems to work i feel like i am missing something really obvious?

Can someone point me in the right direction.

I expect that there should be an allow origin header:

[image]

I also tried using the Mosif browser extension to turn cors on, this stoped the cors error from showing but now i have a 404 (notfound ) on:

> https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/domainname.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_sign_up/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration

Comment: What auth library are you using? And is that an OPTIONS request?

Comment: @JasSuri b2cauth, and what do you mean by options request? it is a user sign in/sign up request if that helps?

Comment: @JasSuri i am using react-azure-adb2c

Comment: As a sidenote, I would suggest switching to a different react library. The one you are using is not really being maintained. We are currently using https://github.com/syncweek-react-aad/react-aad

Comment: Changed to use the library you are using and not a single problem , thank for the advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention that you get an 404 error when opening the `openid-configuration` url. This means that part of your configuration is incorrect. **You must be able to open this url in your browser and get back a JSON document.** Copy it to a new tab and tweak it until you get back a result.

Please double check your configured policy and tenant name. The full url usually looks like this:

```
https://tenantname.b2clogin.com/tenantname.onmicrosoft.com/<policy-name>/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration
https://tenantname.b2clogin.com/tenantname.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration?p=<policy-name>
https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/tenantname.onmicrosoft.com/<policy-name>/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration
```

All of these are equally valid and can be used depending on your scenario.

The config should then look something like this:

```
authentication.initialize({
    instance: 'https://tenantname.b2clogin.com/',
    tenant: 'tenantname.onmicrosoft.com',
```

Another issue might be if your B2C tenant quite new, [Microsoft could be blocking support for microsoftonline for your tenant](https://github.com/azure-deprecation/dashboard/issues/29). In this case, try switching to the b2clogin.com domain as your instance.

You can see a possible value for this url when opening the user flow in the Azure Portal.

As a sidenote, I would suggest switching to a different react library. The one you are using is not really being maintained. We are currently using https://github.com/syncweek-react-aad/react-aad

[image: USer Flow]

[image: run now]