# 404 error while accessing token service of Azure B2C

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I am trying to call the rest service for getting idToken from Azure B2C application using following URL:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token?p={POLICY}
```

I am passing all the required parameters in the payload :

```
grant_type=authorization_code&client_id={ClientID}&scope=https://{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/api/read openid offline_access&code={AUTH_CODE}&redirect_uri={REDIRECT_URI}&client_secret={CLIENT_KEY}
```

The same approach is working on one environment but returns
404 : The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

when accessing from another environment.

What am I missing here? Any Azure configuration that I need to check?

Comment: Try b2clogin.com https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/b2clogin new tenants cannot access the old URLs

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cors no-access-control-allow-origin when trying to call B2C login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62975275/cors-no-access-control-allow-origin-when-trying-to-call-b2c-login)

Comment: Your first response did help me to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your request looks good. So the key point of this issue should not be in B2C side.

This error generally means that the file you are looking is not present on the server or `web.config` file is not configured properly.

As the approach is working on one environment but failing for another, you should check the `web.config` file which is in the failing environment to see if it is configured correctly.

See a similar question [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4eed0a29-9b30-498d-91bf-022157884751/the-resource-you-are-looking-for-has-been-removed-had-its-name-changed-or-is-temporarily?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview).